# Why is JavaScript wrapInner throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, runtime-error

I have a Firefox addon with the following code:

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td[width='600']").wrapInner("<div id='content_cont' />");
```

That line of code executes, but all the lines after it don't. It throws an error that has a code that's over 500KB in the Firefox error console.

CODE:

```
An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid0-ib8arkgejpxo7qidkuieut5rquk-at-jetpack/flvs-educator-release-version/data/redesign.js", line 49, in 
    $("table > tbody > tr > td[width='600']").wrapInner("<div id='content_cont' />");
  File "resource://jid0-ib8arkgejpxo7qidkuieut5rquk-at-jetpack/flvs-educator-release-version/data/jquery.js", line 2, in .wrapInner
    (function(a,b){function G(a){var b=F[a]={};return p.each(a.split(s)...<tons of meaningless code>...&define("jquery",[],function(){return p})})(window);
ReferenceError: Begin is not defined
```

I can't figure out why it's doing this. Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Use a non-minified version of jQuery to debug

Comment: I don't have any experience working with jQuery; I just started using it on this project. I wouldn't have any idea how to debug it.

Comment: That doesn't matter - but only with a non-minified (and recent?) version it will be possible to locate the error.

Comment: @epascarello: the page is not 500KB, but the error code in the Mozilla Error Console is.

Comment: @bergi: sorry if I sound really stupid here, but how would I go about finding the error?

Comment: Use a non-minified version of jQuery. Then the error message will not contain the whole file, but only the line where the exception occured; you can post that and we can dig in.

Comment: Alright, here is the error code with the non-minified version: http://pastebin.com/vjEGRYz2

Comment: @epascarello: jquery is minified, so it's basically one loooong line of code, which gets logged to the console.

Comment: One thing, ids are singular, so you can not wrap all of those elements with the same id. You should be using class there if you need to reference it in the future. Also try not using empty tag notation with the div and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @epascarello: A: There should only be one element that matches the ID, so it's just one big div, right? B: I tried using `wrapInner("<div id='content_cont'> </div>");`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I went ahead and tried it with `class`. I got the same display on the page, and the same error code.

Comment: [This is a working example](http://jsbin.com/ifusug/1/edit), the error is after this code.

Comment: Post more code, what you have after the line.

Comment: @sheikh: That is the last line in the code because everything after it breaks. If you're using Firefox, I can give you a demo: Install this addon: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/154879/latest/, and go to demo.flvs.net, and sign in with username and password: demo. It may display strangely in some parts, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the content you are wrapping contains any `script` elements, then `wrapInner` will execute them again, even if they ran when the page first loaded. See [Ticket #9134](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9134) on jQuery's bug tracker for some more information.

It looks like there is an error in the one of the `script` elements inside the content you are wrapping, and that error is preventing your code from continuing to execute past the `wrapInner` call. The error may be occurring because the code assumes that it will only ever be run once. The simplest solution might be to just remove any `script` elements from the content before wrapping it:

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td[width='600']").find('script')
  .remove()
.end().wrapInner("<div id='content_cont' />");
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you're a lifesaver! It won't let me award the bounty for another 22 hours.